# How do I connect the output of a math node to the offset of an image texture node?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I have been recently making animated Minecraft textures for myself. To make an animated texture, you have to order the different frames in top-down order, like this.

[image]I usually do it in GIMP, but I felt that I could do it in Blender too.

I tried to control the offset of an Image Texture node (with a movie clip), but it seemed that it had no input.

[image]

Is it even possible to drive the Offset using a Math node? If so, please tell me how.

Comment: Do you mean offset in time, of an image sequence, or offset in space, of a single image?

Comment: Offset in time, sorry! As in the frames.

Comment: No apology needed, that's what the missing input would do.. I was just confused by the other image

Comment: The first image is a texture of an animated torch readable by Minecraft. The game takes the width of the image (8 px) and then assumes that each 8x8 square in the image is a frame. It then reads the frames from top to bottom.

Comment: I don't _think_ there's a way with nodes, they are compiled before the renderer uses them.. (I could be wrong). But if you have a folder of frames, say, labeled `000x.png`, and _imagemagick_ installed, it's a command-line one liner, run from a terminal in the directory: `convert 0*.png -append mytexture.png` will do it. I believe it can also be done from the Windows power shell? (If you needed to resize the frames, you may need a `-geometry` argument,as well)